# $f^{-1}(U)$ is regular open set in $X$ for regular open set $U$ in $Y$, whenever $f$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function from space $X$ to space $Y$. If $U$ is regular open set in $Y$, it it true that $f^{-1}(U)$ is a [regular open set](http://planetmath.org/regularopenset) in $X$?

Comment: What is regular open？

Comment: @Paul: An open subset $U$ of a space $Y$ is said to be regular open in $Y$ if $U$ is the interior of its closure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not necessarily.  Consider the absolute value function $x \mapsto | x |$, and the inverse image of $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

As arjafi explains, the answer is 'no.' Further to that, adding smoothness conditions won't help either. For example, consider $$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$f(x) = x^2$$

Then:

- $f^{-1}(0,1) = (-1,0) \cup (0,1),$ so preimages of regular open sets needn't be regular open.
- $f^{-1}[-1,0] = \{0\},$ so preimages of regular closed sets needn't be regular closed.