# Continuous maps and frame homomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, order-theory, lattice-orders

Given a continuous map $f : X \rightarrow Y$ between topological spaces, we get a function $\mathcal{O}(f) : \mathcal{O}(Y) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(X)$ defined by taking preimages. This is always a frame homomorphism, meaning that it preserves finite meets and arbitrary joins.

> **Question.** Is it possible for $\mathcal{O}(f)$ to fail to preserve pseudocomplements?

(By the pseudocomplement of an open set $U$, I mean the interior of its complement.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any pseudocomplement is necessarily a regular open set: a set equal to the interior of its complement. As you correctly pointed out in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2403262), the preimage of $(0,1)$ under the squaring map ($x\mapsto x^2$ from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology) is $(-1,0) \cup (0,1),$ which is not regular.

Comment: So in particular, letting $U = (-\infty,0)\cup (1,\infty)$, we have that the preimage of the pseudocomplement of $U$ is $(-1,0)\cup (0,1)$, while the pseudocomplement of the preimage of $U$ is $(-1,1)$.